# SpringBoot Kafka autoconfig - keystore location prefixed with exploded war directory name

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-kafka, spring-autoconfiguration

In my property file I have 
`spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=${javax.net.ssl.keyStore:}`

Operations confirmed that `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/app/config/keystore.jks` is being called to start Tomcat.

Just to verify I added

```
@Value('${javax.net.ssl.keyStore:}')
String keystore
@Value('${spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location:}')
String springKeystore
```

to one of my components and confirmed that the values are `/opt/app/config/keystore.jks`
But the app errors out with

```
 org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /opt/app/webapps/ROOT/opt/app/config/keystore.jks of type JKS
 Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/app/webapps/ROOT/opt/app/config/keystore.jks
```

I confirmed that `/opt/app/webapps/ROOT` is where the war is exploded.  So I am confused as to why the war file location is being prefixed to the keystore location when autoconfiguring the Kafka client.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to add "file:" as in
`spring.kafka.consumer.ssl.key-store-location=file:${javax.net.ssl.keyStore}`